# facing wrong Json format while content is correct

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am facing some error while fetching the json. It shows wrong format.Here is the following json

```
{
"favorite_page_response": "<div class=\"col-md-12 col-lg-12\">\n              <div class=\"cart\">\n        
  <div class=\"cart-heading\">\n                     <h1>Favorites<\/h1>\n                <div class=
 \"cart-items\">Favorite Items:<span><a href=\"javascript:;\">0<\/a><\/span><\/div>\n              <\
/div>\n              <a class=\"clear-cart\" href=\"javascript:;\" >Clear Favorites<\/a> <\/div>\n  
      <div class=\"cart-product\">\n              <ul>\n                  \n           \n       
 <\/ul>\n        <\/div>\n    <\/div>",
"status": 1
 }
```

Can anyone let me know what am doing wrong.

Comment: where does the json come from? we need some more information

Comment: php,, i using json_encode method for it.

Comment: So show us exactly how you're creating that JSON with the exact code that you used. You've made a mistake somewhere and we can't guess where.

Answer (score 0):

There many errors in this json:

1. `\"` can be replaced be `'`
2. `\n` is not required.
3. There should be **no white spaces** in the response string it should be single line.